# Simplify JSON serialization in @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I have a question about ORM mapping with Spring JPA.

Consider a simple class Person:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false, name = "PERSON_ID")
    private long personId;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Car> cars;

    public Person() {
    } 
    //continue....
```

and a simple class Car:

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CAR_ID")
    private long carId;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Person person;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String typeOfCar;

    public Car() {
    } 
    //continue....
```

Person has a OneToMany relationship with Car.

Recalling that carId is auto-generated, when I POST a new car at the moment I am forced to specify a full Person object (apart from the nullable list of cars):

```
{
  "person": {
    "personId": 200,
    "name": "Jack"
  },
  "typeOfCar": "Ferrari"
}
```

I would like to be able to POST a car object just like this:

```
{
  "person": 200,
  "typeOfCar": "Ferrari"
}
```

thus specifying only the personId (key of the Person entity).

I guess that I need the Person reference in Car to be serialized only as its key and not as the whole object.

How to achieve this?

So far, what I have tried are the following annotations *@JsonIdentityReference* and *@JsonIdentityInfo* on the Person reference in Car as follows:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "personId")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
private Person person;
```

but when I POST the simplified JSON I am getting the following 404:

```
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message": "JSON parse error: Unresolved forward references for: ; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference: Unresolved forward references for: \n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@25614608; line: 5, column: 1]Object id [2] (for myapp.ws.people.entity.Person) at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@25614608; line: 2, column: 13].",
```

Comment: Can you use criteria query or JPQL?

Comment: delete @not null at Join Column

Comment: No I can not use JPQL. Deleting @NotNull did not change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one way to achieve it is to

1. create a DTO class

   ```
   class CarDto {
   private long person;
   private String typeOfCar;
   }
   ```
2. then in your service have 2 repositories. one for person and other for car.

   ```
   class PersonService {

     public void post(CarDto car) {
      Person person = personRepository.findByPersonId(car.getPerson());
      Car newCar = new Car();
      newCar.setPerson(person);
      newCar.setTypeOfCar(car.getTypeOfCar);
      carRepository.save(newCar);
     }

   }
   ```

Comment: i think you asked how to achieve the post call you want to make. So this is one approach. U should create a DTO class and then use that as request body in the controller and call your service method like mentioned in the answer. Creating DTO classes is very common method to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer